# Failed to resolve: androidx.compose ... 1.4.0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

As per latest https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

I can see that we can use

- Compose Compiler Version  - 1.4.0
- Compatible Kotlin Version - 1.8.0

However, after upgrade to compose 1.4.0 and kotlin 1.8.0, I got the error below

I got this error

```
Failed to resolve: androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.4.0
Failed to resolve: androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.4.0
Failed to resolve: androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.0
Failed to resolve: androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.4.0
Failed to resolve: androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.4.0
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: 1.4.0 exists only for the compiler

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the libraries from the `androidx.compose.ui` package for compose version `1.4.0` have not been released yet.

The latest version for each of these libs is `1.4.0-alpha04`. You can check the versions on [this page](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=androidx.compose.ui#androidx.compose.ui:ui)

Answer (score 3):

Compose compiler and the other compose dependencies have [different releases](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose).
Currently only `compose.compiler` has **1.4.0** stable.

To avoid this kind of problem you have different option:

**Use the [BOM](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose)**

> The Compose Bill of Materials (BOM) lets you manage all of your Compose library versions by specifying only the BOM’s version. The BOM itself has links to the stable versions of the different Compose libraries, in such a way that they work well together.
> Going forward, Compose libraries will be versioned independently, which means version numbers will start to be incremented at their own pace.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#using-the-bom) you can find more info about BOM.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_compiler = '1.4.0'  //compiler
    }
    //...
}

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_compiler
}

dependencies {
    // Import the Compose BOM
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.12.00')

    //....

}
```

**Or use different version in your build script**:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_compiler = '1.4.0'  //compiler
        compose_version = '1.3.x'   //compose dependencies
        compose_material3 = '1.0.1' //material3 release
    }
    //...
}
```

and then:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_compiler
}

dependencies {
   // compose releases (1.3.x)
   implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
   //... 

   //material3
   implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:$compose_material3"
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of using `platform` in BOM?

Comment: @VivekModi A platform is a special software component which can be used to control transitive dependency versions. More info [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:using-platform-to-control-transitive-deps)

Answer (score 1):

Don’t forget to import the BOM in your module’s build.gradle (app module too)

```
val composeBom = platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom)
implementation(composeBom)
androidTestImplementation(composeBom)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the compose version and composeCompiler version are different.

For now, the compose version is at `1.4.0-alpha04`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.4.0-alpha04'
    }
}
```

While the composeCompiler is now 1.4.0

```
android {
    ...
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
    }
}
```